# file descriptor is too large for select()

Tags: kernel, 20.10, ulimit

I'm locally running an R script which involves opening a very large number of files, and also generating a lot of temporary files and storing them in `/tmp/Rtmpxxxx`. Initially it crashed because my `ulimit -n` was set too low, so I increased `ulimit -n` from 1024 to 1000000.

However, the R script still crashes:

```
Error in selectChildren(ac[!fin], -1) : 
  file descriptor is too large for select()
```

I checked `cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max` which returned 9223372036854775807, which is presumably the largest value avaliable for a 64-bit signed integer. I'm definitely not opening that many files, so I am wondering why the error still appears?

```
sam@sam:~/$ ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 256509
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 8215701
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1000000
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 256509
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```